# Store a React.FC in a generic typed variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to find a way to store any `React.FC` in a variable.

So, I wrote the following code:

```
type CompoDefinition = {
    Compo: React.FC
}
type CompoAProps = {
    a: string
}
function CompoA(props: CompoAProps) {
    return <div>{props.a}</div>
}
type CompoBProps = {
    b: number
}
function CompoB(props: CompoBProps) {
    return <div>{props.b}</div>
}
const F: CompoDefinition = {
    Compo: CompoA
}
```

Now, I get the following error:
`Type '(props: CompoAProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'`

It seems that `React.FC` is understood as `React.FC<{}>` which I understand, but I don't know how to resolve my issue: how to declare a variable that can be affected with "any React.FC"?

I could use `React.FC<any>` but my linter is not happy with it.

Comment: I don't see any other simple but effective way without `any`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got what I wanted by typing my FC properties like that:

```
type GenericProps = {
  [key: string]: unknown;
};

type CompoDefinition = {
    Compo: React.FC<GenericProps>
}

(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try that and see if your linter says anything:

```
type CompoDefinition<T = any> = {
  Compo: React.FC<T>;
};
```

Comment: nay :/ `warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any` thanks anyway